# Can NSUUID be extended by inheritance? How?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6, nsuuid

Recently (reviewing some code) I stumbled upon an oddity that results in a bug in our program.

An API we are using has the following implementation (that I am going to write in Swift, even though the original code is in Objective-C)

```swift
internal class MyUUID: NSUUID { }
```

Which is completely useless as it always returns an empty instance.

I am going to paste the code from my playground here for explanation purposes.

For example: creating a simple NSUUID would be something like this:

```swift
let a = NSUUID()
a.description //this creates a valid uuid
```

While creating a MyUUID should be similar

```swift
let b = MyUUID()
b.description //it returns an instance, but is completely empty.
```

But it doesn't work.

Inspecting a little bit more, reveals the NSUUID initialiser creates a `__NSConcreteUUID` instance, while MyUUID doesn't and it doesn't matter what I try to do, it won't create an appropriate UUID.

So, my question: Is it possible to be able to create a child implementation of NSUUID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `class_setSuperclass` to change the superclass of `MyUUID` at runtime. This approach would be illegal in Swift, due to type safety, but you could still do it in Objective-C.

Depending on your actual goals you may be able to use [CFUUIDRef](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFUUIDRef) instead.

---

As requested, here's an example of the `class_setSuperclass` approach. Just drop this in to a new single view project.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface MyUUID : NSUUID

- (void) UUIDWithHello;

@end

@implementation MyUUID

- (void) UUIDWithHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello! %@", self.UUIDString);
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Make a UUID that you want to subclass
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Initial UUID: %@", uuid.UUIDString);

    // Ignore deprecation warnings, since class_setSuperclass is deprecated
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

    // Change MyUUID to inherit from the NSUUID's hidden subclass instead of NSUUID
    class_setSuperclass([MyUUID class], [uuid class]);  // [uuid class] is __NSConcreteUUID

    // Turn deprecation warnings back on
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

    // Make a new myUUID and print it
    MyUUID *myUuid = [[MyUUID alloc] init];
    [myUuid UUIDWithHello];
}

@end
```

Note that this is a bit dangerous. If whatever secret subclass `NSUUID` has additional instance variables, it will require more memory, which `[MyUUID alloc]` won't request. This could cause a crash later when something requests these instance variables.

To get around this, you could instead instantiate your `MyUUID` instance like this:

```
NSLog(@"Initial UUID's class: %@", NSStringFromClass(uuid.class));
Class topSecretUUIDSubclass = uuid.class; // __NSConcreteUUID
MyUUID *myUuid2 = [[topSecretUUIDSubclass alloc] init];
[myUuid2 UUIDWithHello];
object_setClass(myUuid2, [MyUUID class]);
```

Basically this will make `myUuid2` a `__NSConcreteUUID` and then change it to a `MyUUID`. However, this will only work if `MyUUID` doesn't add any instance variables.

If `MyUUID` *does* need to add its own instance variables, it will need to override `+alloc` to provide additional memory for these instance variables, using `class_createInstance()`.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of this?

Comment: The 'objc_setSuperclass' approach :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just change the superclass dynamically in +initialize?  Also, why would the first approach be dangerous?  You're changing the class's notion of its superclass, so [MyUUID alloc] should then call [__NSConcreteWhatever alloc], no?

Comment: Never mind.  I know what you're saying.  The underlying struct would collide with the underlying struct for the new superclass.  Yes, that makes this a bad idea.  :-/

Answer (score 3):

Your evidence would appear empirically to answer your own question: it's not possible. `NSUUID` would appear to be a class cluster rather than a single class, which effectively prevents subclassing.

An alternative idea to Aaron's:

Implement an object that has an `NSUUID` rather than that is one. Implement `-forwardingTargetForSelector:` and return your instance of `NSUUID`. Consider overriding `-isKindOfClass:`, but ideally don't unless you have to. Then you should be able to pass your class as though it were an `NSUUID` to anyone that expects one without their knowing the difference.

Given that the solution depends upon the fallback mechanism built into dynamic messaging, I suspect there's no Swift equivalent; however if you define your class as Objective-C then it should be equally usable from Swift.

Comment: I think I like your answer more, but I've updated my answer with some more details. I think I provided an okay (albeit dangerous and deprecated) way to subclass a class cluster - would like a second pair of eyes on my solution though.

Comment: If I may re-awaken this thread: I wanted to do something similar, where for convenience, I wanted a UUID's `description` to be just the UUIDString, not the `<__NSConcreteUUID <memory address> <UUID>>` format. Even in Swift 2.2, is this still my only option? I don't want to have Obj-C code just for the sake of this convenience.